# This page isn’t working...If the problem continues, contact the site owner. HTTP ERROR 405

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making this simple login form using html css and js. And I am receiving this error when i click the login button: This page isn’t working...If the problem continues, contact the site owner. HTTP ERROR 405.
Below are the codes:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function validate(){
  var username = document.getElementById(username).value
  var password = document.getElementById(password).value
  if(username == "judge1" && password=="1234") {
    alert("Login Successful");
    return false;
  }
  else{
    alert("Login Failed");
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form class="inputs" action="/" method="POST">
        <input type="text" class="username" placeholder="Username" id="username"> <br/>
        <input type="password" class="password" placeholder="Password" id="password"> <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="validate()">
    </form>
```

I tried googling it but I'm having a hard time in finding the solution. I am still new in this so please help.

Comment: Could you show us the complete code? Where are you dealing with the posted data? Are you using PHP for example on your backend? You can't 'log a user in' safely just in the frontend - anyone could inspect the code using their browser's devtools and find that built-in password

Comment: JS cannot give 405. It is a server issue - for example if you want to POSST to get the page

Comment: Have you got a backend or do you want everything done in the frontend?

Answer (score 0):

There is a little error in getting username and password to variables. you should give element ids in string types and use ';' to end.

```
var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
```

however I think its better to call validate function using onsubmit event from the form

then you can prevent redirecting to the action page by returning false from your validate();

Comment: yes, I read it and I run that code and I found that the JavaScript doesn't work because the syntax errors in first 2 lines and it redirected the user to action page given under form action attribute . it open the home page. If there was no home page browser will show 405 error.

Comment: The lack of quotes is not creating the 405 error.

Comment: @AHaworth Sorry for my poor explanation,

Comment: 405 error is not creating by that missing quotes, that missing quotes will make that whole javascript workless so when user clicked on submit button browser will open new page instantly (in this case this new page should be a missing page thats why it show error 405). so after correcting that missing quotations the javaScript will run correctly but after clicking "ok" on alert browser will show 405 error. to avoid from getting this error, you can give the action page correctly, or you can stop submitting the values to action page if it's not necessary.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because while accessing the username and password in the javascript code you are doing one thing wrong which is :

We must use `quotes around id` while accessing HTML Code in JS.

And Also, while submitting the Form, you are not using `event.preventDefault()`. This is basically used to prevent the default behavior of an event here like in the form submission. If we are not using this then it will stop the form from submitting anything because some additional checks and validations are required before submission. But often we don't want to apply that checks so its solution is using `event.preventDefault()`.
So this can be corrected as :

```
function validate(event){
  event.preventDefault(); //  this will prevent form submission
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value; //  missing quotes around id
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value; //  missing quotes around id
  if(username == "judge1" && password=="1234") {
    alert("Login Successful");
  }
  else{
    alert("Login Failed");
  }
}
```

Comment: The lack of quotes is not why they are getting the 405 error. The 405 error is caused by submitting (POSTing) the form to somewhere that doesn't support it. You are getting round that by preventing the default action, but without describing why this is helping.

Comment: Okay sure @AHaworth, I will explain this in this post. Thaks for pointing out.

Comment: To use your code, you need to do `document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", validate)` but your code will ALWAYS block submission. The event.preventDefault needs to be in the else statement

Answer (score 0):

I can already spot some issues with your code:

- When using **type="submit"** the browser will send the form and it wont care much about any functions being executed, so adding **onclick** is pointless since you are leaving the page anyway, So remove **type="submit"** or add **onsubmit="return false;"** to the form tag.
- On the JS side, you should add double-quotes when passing the ID name to **getElementById**

```js
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you so much for your help. I've applied your suggestion and it worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are SEVERAL errors. I will explain them one by one

1. You are always submitting the form, it is POSTed to the root, which likely is a "welcome.html", "index.html" or similar page that expects a GET. Hence the 405
2. IF you want to validate the form, use the submit event
3. You need to quote the IDs of the fields in getElementById

Here is a fixed form with a fixed script, using recommended event handling

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { // when the page has loaded

  document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    let username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    let password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    if (username === "judge1" && password === "1234") {
      alert("Login Successful");
      return true; // allow the submit
    }
    // no need to have an else after a return
    alert("Login Failed");
    e.preventDefault(); // do NOT submit the form
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="myForm" class="inputs" action="/somepostacceptingcode.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" class="username" placeholder="Username" id="username"> <br/>
  <input type="password" class="password" placeholder="Password" id="password"> <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```